# Does wearing magic items with armor affect AC negatively?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, armor, armor-class

If I’m wearing a set of full plate  armor and I replace the gauntlets with gauntlets of ogre strength do I lose the AC provided by the full plate as I’m no longer wearing a full set of full plate armor?

Comment: I don’t see anything addressing AC in the previous question, so I’m not sure if that makes it distinct enough. The previous question merely seems to be asking if it’s possible not what the AC effects are from doing so

Comment: Related on [Can you wear magical boots/gloves/gauntlets with plate armor?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138012)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No, because the rules don't say so

The rules don't really manage that level of granularity with armor. Plate is plate, and if you take off the boots or gloves, the rules don't seem to care. (thanks @ThomasMarkov for the summarizing)

[Gauntlets of Ogre Power](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/gauntlets-of-ogre-power) description doesn't say the item decreases a full plate's AC, so it doesn't. There are no secret rules:

> Beware of claims that a rule does something mentioned nowhere in that rule or elsewhere in the core books. There aren't secret rules. ([source](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/857269923134939136))

From the simulationist's point of view, one can rationalize it as the character *replaces* one pair of gauntlets with another one, so the "total" AC remains the same.

Related questions:

- [Is partial armour an optional rule?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/119358/)
- [Combining various AC-providing clothing and armor](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/57309/)
- [Do gauntlets do anything?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51517/)

The Standard Caveat™: D&D 5th edition enforces the "rulings over rules" principle — it empowers the DM in ways that 3rd, 3.5, and 4th did not. While rule zero has always applied, 5th edition chooses not to explicitly codify many things. If your DM says your AC is lowered, it is. However, I've never seen anyone justified wearing magic gauntlets this way.

Comment: So you don’t have to wear a full set of a suit of armors component pieces to maintain the armors AC rating? You can mix and match?

Comment: @MichelleSims The rules dont really manage that level of granularity with armor. Plate is plate, and if you take off the boots or gloves, the rules dont seem to care.

Comment: @MichelleSims Armor generally is intended to protect your body, not as much your limbs, but even in that case, Gauntlets of Ogre Strength are *still gauntlets*, so you're swapping a set of normal gauntlets for a set of magical gauntlets, which would probably provide at *least* the same amount of protection as the mundane ones.

Comment: @MichelleSims the right answer is "ask your DM". However, I see no problem here. When you take off your gauntlets and don Gauntlets of Ogre Power, you still "wear a full set of a suit of armor".

Comment: +1 Agree - if using the magic gauntlets affected AC negatively, it would say so in the description of the  magical item.

Comment: Another thing to consider. You could have a wizard/sorcerer/some other class with no armor proficiency equip gauntlets of ogre power. This doesn't hinder their spellcasting though, even though they aren't proficient with any armor and are now wearing metal gloves. Magical items like this just get hand waved away.